# Regex greedy match failed?

Tags: regex

I have the below 2 lines out of other lines that I need to match.

```
2015 - 2016 2016 - 2017 2017 - 2018 2018 - 2019 2019 - 2020 2020 
2015 - 2016 2016 - 2017 2017 - 2018 2018 - 2019 2019 - 2020 APR 2021
```

Top is to be able to match and the get the year value '`2020`' and bottom is match and get the month and the year value '`APR 2021`'.

I'm able to match both using this regex (`^\d.*(?<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})?\s(?<year>\d{4})$`) to match these 2 lines but for the bottom matched line, it does not give me the month value.

Any idea?

This is the output from
[regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB0NV.png)

Comment: Good that you have shared your efforts, could you please post sample of expected output also in your question, thank you.

Comment: Use a non greedy `.*?` like `^\d.*?(?<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})?\s(?<year>\d{4})$` https://regex101.com/r/3EdBWW/1

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve `2020` for the 1st line. What is the logic there?

Comment: suggestion : paste a link to regex101, rather than a screen capture. Also : please explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If all characters that aren't in month names are all going to be digits, dashes and spaces, explicitly match those (e.g: `[0-9\- ]*`) rather than anything (e.g : `.*`) :

```
# 'anything goes' matched here
#     v
^\d[0-9 \-]*(?<month>[a-zA-Z]{3})?\s(?<year>\d{4})$
```